# Time complexity of indirect recursion

Tags: computer-science, recursive-algorithms, recursion

How to find the complexity of an the given algorithm:

Algorithm f(int n)

{

```
if(n==1)return(1);

else
{
  f(n-1)+g(n-1);
}
```

}

Algorithm g(int n)

{

```
if(n==2)return(1);
else
{
  f(n-1)+g(n/2);
}
```

}

The answer is O(2^n), But how?

Comment: Check the answer of this question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270105/runtime-analysis-of-a-recursive-function-that-calls-another-recursive-function][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270105/runtime-analysis-of-a-recursive-function-that-calls-another-recursive-function

Answer (score 1):

Set up two variables (for $f$ and $g$) and define a system of recurrences.